# upgrading to java 17 spring boot 3 getting build issues in build pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-17

Getting below gradle build error while trying to upgrade java 17.

```
      - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
          - Other compatible attribute:
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
      - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
          - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
          - Other compatible attribute:
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')

              - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
              - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
              - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Error: The process '/azp/agent/_work/1/s/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
at ExecState._setResult (/azp/agent/_work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/3.221.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:943:25)
at ExecState.CheckComplete (/azp/agent/_work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/3.221.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:926:18)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/azp/agent/_work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/3.221.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:839:19)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore

Comment: SB3.x.x requires Java 17.  Are you either using JDK11 or setting `sourceCompatibility` or `targetCompatibility` to J11?  Also, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72117858/incompatible-because-this-component-declares-a-component-compatible-with-java-11

Comment: I am using sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17' . the issue is not on my local. It is working fine on my local. The issue is in the build pipeline. Agent fails before it actually starts build process.