# Error while committing code back to Github from android studio

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, gradle, git-bash

Can anybody help me with this , i'm able to commit changes from both git bash and android studio initially , but as soon as i test the app in android studio {i.e build it .} after that i'm unable to commit and push the changes anymore and getting this as error
[error from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeqRo.png)
[error from git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/174H4.png)

i'm unable to find any solution to it :(

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Use a more descriptive title. Include the files necessary to reproduce the problem, like your buildscript and linter configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72117858/incompatible-because-this-component-declares-a-component-compatible-with-java-11)